# Baking/UV issue - I thought i had a done a good job! :)

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-baking

I thought i had done a good job retopologizing my highpoly mesh,
and i expected a decent bake, but i have some pretty terrible things
going on. what's going on in the pic?do i merely need to move these verts along the y axis?

[image]

Here is the normal

[image]

Here's the UV

[image]

Comment: Probably you didn't set the HiPoly to smooth shading. Then there can be a wrong value (0) of the ray distance in the "selected to active" tab. Third, can you show the wireframe of the Lo Poly mesh and the normal map you baked? Or upload your file?

Comment: I would, but i'm on my way to Nicaragua! Cheers thanks so much for responding!